# Counter with 4 flip flops jk synchronous from 3 to 13!

Tags: circuit-analysis, flipflop, counter, synchronous, logisim

I have to create a counter with 4 flip flops jk synchronous. The counter shall count in this order: 3 to 13 and then to 3 to 13 and so on..

I have to use logisim simulator.

Ok. So i think its solved. I realized that the circuit needs to start at 0 ou 1 and stabilize after the 13 and then it goes to 3. Thanks for your help. 
Hope this will help for somebody else too. 
Thank you all for your help!

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you want the counter to do.

Comment: @EMFields Indeed! bad writing,...

Comment: Sorry! English is not my first language... -_-

Comment: Try to bring more structure into your questions. And by the way, we can see, that you are new here, you don't have to point that out.

Comment: Is that in the upper left corner an input pad that you set to 1? Then there is definitely a problem when you connect that to the NAND gate on the bottom right (since there are two inputs that want to drive the line to different levels). I guess you wanted to use that NAND to create the reset?

Also: putting a constant 1/true into all those AND gates on the top does nothing: I would remove them to make the diagram less confusing to you and others.

Comment: You´re right! I figured that putting a constant 1/true into all those AND gates was useless... can you explain me how to use the nand to reset the counter?

Comment: Never write in all-capitals on the web.  Ever.

Answer (score 2):

The Q outputs give the current count/state, the J and K inputs indicate what they need to be for the next count.

The following would be a simple counter, as the way you have implemented (but without hold function):

```
Q3 Q2 Q1 Q0  J3 K3  J2 K2  J1 K1  J0 K0
0  0  0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   1  1
0  0  0  1   0  0   0  0   1  1   1  1
0  0  1  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   1  1
...
1  1  0  1   0  0   0  0   1  1   1  1  "count 13"
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

To implement the restart, you can change the J, K inputs at count 13 like this:

```
1  1  0  1   0  1   0  1   0  1   0  1  (to set all Q's to 0 next state)
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Alternately,

```
1  1  0  1   x  1   x  1   0  x   x  1
```

knowing the existing Q outputs, you only need to force certain J's and K's to get all 0 next state, while leaving the other J's and K's as don't care to minimize logic.

Compare this to the line labeled "count 13", the only changes needed from the simple counter are 3 bits, J1, K2, K3.

To implement the 3 to 13 counter, do the same things, except arrange the J and K inputs at count 13 such that the next state will give you 3.

---

Response to comment and fixed mistakes:

[image]

The blue modification serves the purpose of:
At count-13, force the three lines J1, K2, K3 to deviate from the normal count sequence that are necessary to give the desired count/state on next clock.

I am not sure you realize this, the 3-input And gate does not decode just count-13, it also goes true at count-15. But it does work fine the way as is because count-15 will never be reached during normal operation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think i got it now!!! Im going to try this.

Comment: I don't use logisim, but if you would edit your post and attach your new schematic...

Comment: Add your new schematic to the question by editing it.

Comment: Still cant figure it out how to put the count to 3 to 13 without screwing out the count ou 5 ou 6...

Comment: you probably need to use wider and gates. also the input to the first flip-flop is wrong if it needs to go  from 13 back to 3

Comment: @CP_PT, can you at least come up with what the J and K inputs need to be at count-13 such that the next state will be 3 (in text format like the table I put up)?

Comment: @rioraxe No. I tried but then when i go to the logisim it doesn´t work. Can you please help me? Its the last time i swear! I wont trouble you again! And thank you so much for your help! Im reaaly struggling with this... even tough im studying really hard..

Comment: Show what the J and K inputs need to be at count-13 such that the next state will be 3 (in text format like the table I put up) so we can review it.

Comment: Show what the J and K inputs need to be such that the next state will be 3. If you cannot do even this, I cannot help you.

Comment: @rioraxe the J0K0 has to 1 for the Q0 to be 1 and the same for the J1K1 for the Q1 to be 1, so it counts at the beginning 3 right?

Comment: No, at count-13, Q0 is already 1, if J0,K0 are 1, then what will Q0 be next state. Please look at a truth table of a JK flipflop.

Comment: Q0 will be 0 at the next stage that i got it. how can i make it so that only at the transition from 13 to 3 it stays at 1 the Q0  and Q1 too to be 1 to at the beginning?

Comment: You have to figure out at count-13 what J and K's need to be such that the next state will be 3, then you change the circuit to only modify J and K at count-13. But first, you must figure out what J and K needs to be at count-13, then you can figure out how to modify the circuit later.

Comment: This is my final attempt: what do the J and K inputs have to be at count-13 such that the next state will be 3, such that (Q3,Q2,Q1,Q0) = (0,0,1,1)? I am going to sleep.

Comment: @rioraxe i think i finally going very close to finish. See what i did. How can i add right at beginning the 3 without the 13 before??

Comment: @rioraxe please help... since last night that im stuck at this point... :(

Comment: @rioraxe dont give up on me! :/

Comment: @jasen can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the 0 (i.e. asynchroneous reset) input on the flip flops the problem becomes a little bit easier:

[image]

Since your questions sounds a lot like homework I will let you figure out what signal to feed into the reset inputs (I placed a dummy circuit in my figure, so the output is undefined / blue).

Hint for the 3 to 13 counter: read the reference on the JK flip flop and see what you can do with the other inputs.

Comment: The use of asynchronous reset is a truly bad and unreliable technique here. The gate that produces the reset pulse will deassert the reset signal as soon as one FF changes state making the gate output a narrow pulse indeed. There is NO guarantee that the narrow pulse will be wide enough to assure that the other FFs will also clear.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: Good point. As more of a software person I did not catch that. I came up with a solution that buffered the reset signal for 1 cycle using a D flip flop, but I'm not sure if that would be a viable way to do it outside of a simulation.

Comment: Making the reset 1 clock wide is a good start....but a better strategy would be to gate the FF JK inputs to the desired next state. May be easier with D FFs in many cases.

Comment: ok, i think i got what you´re talking about, but im completely lost. So what should i do with my project? how can i just reset when it counts to 13 and go to zero and then continue the count?

Comment: @0x6d64 can you help me? i cant figure out this!

Comment: @CP_PT: sorry, I don't have that much time. I hope that Jasens answer helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

one more way of making a reset might be by feeding back outputs of flip flops to the reset port.
If I take enable port to be active high the feedback would be like
nand(q3,q2,not(q1),q0) to generate an active low pulse that would reset flipflop after 13.

Comment: The use of asynchronous reset is a truly bad and unreliable technique here. The gate that produces the reset pulse will deassert the reset signal as soon as one FF changes state making the gate output a narrow pulse indeed. There is NO guarantee that the narrow pulse will be wide enough to assure that the other FFs will also clear.

Comment: ok, i think i got what you´re talking about, but im completely lost. So what should i do with my project? how can i just reset when it counts to 13 and go to zero and then continue the count?

Comment: the above method just does that. plz. tell about your confusion in more detail. also note that once the ckt. counts 13 it is reset going back to "0000" then automatically restarts counting.You can see that in excitation table of ckt. too.

Comment: For a more accurate and advanced adaptation of the ckt. take 13 as the terminal count that is create state diagram and excitation tables such that counter goes from 13 to 0. This method is INDEPENDENT of the reset logic.

Comment: Sorry, english is not my first language so i have trouble figuring out what is probably obvious what you all telling me, and thanks in advance for your help. My confusion is that, in my project the simulator stops the count at 13, and i dont know how to connect or what to do so it goes back to 0000 (all flip flops). I tried soo many ways i keep getting nowhere... @_@... help....

Comment: "In this discussion I assume you know fundamentals of circuit design using state diagram and excitation tables.".do one thing first draw ckt. on paper and check the technique in my post i.e with feedback if you find there is no error replicate diagram on simulator ie redraw this entirely. I think that should solve your problem.

Comment: I did the table, but i dont know how to turn all flip flops to 0 after the 13, and then to restart count to 0 to 13... logisim is giving me trouble -_-

Comment: i think a have to do something on the second flip flop, so that in the first count 0 to 13 it works normally and when it comes to 13 i goes 0 so that the rest of the flip flops reset right? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Michael Karas can you help me?

Comment: where r u struck now

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up gates that set the two low order flip flops and clear the two high order ones when the count reaches 13.

Comment: What gates and where shoud i connect? Still didnt understood. Could you make a draw of that?

English is not my first language so i have very trouble understanding what you´re trying to tell me...

Answer (score 0):

here's how I'd do it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUsA99.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: the circuit doesnt work it jumps from 4 to 6 and then 5... and the rest neither... only the beginning is correct...

Comment: isnt it missing 2 OR´s?

Comment: works good when I simulate it.

Comment: observe the ~Q outputs on the first two flip-flops not the Q

Comment: i noticed, i did your schematic on logisim and it didnt work, sorry. Mine´s still better.

Comment: strange, it works fine in circuitlab, it's ready run just click simulate.

Comment: maybe its because of the delay... i dont know.. :/ But thanks for your help! really! ^_^